# How to compare private variables of two classes when trying to overload operator==?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to recreate the string class and am having trouble comparing comparing the two classes against each other as if they are strings. This is what I have in the header file:

```
class Mystring {
public:
   // ...
private:
    // this variable stores the memory address of the text
    char* ptr_buffer

    // ...
};
```

In the source file, I have thsi code:

```
bool operator== (const Mystring& a, const Mystring& b) {
    return a.ptr_buffer == b.ptr_buffer;
}
```

But for some reason when I try to compare two Mystring classes in the main.cpp, it says its unable to access the private variable `ptr_buffer`. I thought it had access to that? How would I compare these two where the only thing that I care about comparing is hidden?

Comment: Post real code, not fake code.  There is no `Class` keyword in C++.  And why are you comparing pointer values?  That won't tell you if two character buffers have equal elements.

Comment: Move the equality operator from global scope into the class: `public: bool operator== (const Mystring& b) { return ptr_buffer == b.ptr_buffer; }` assuming you really want to compare pointers, of course.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of the C++ language, an overloaded operator that's introduced at global scope is just like any other function at global scope (aside from the fact that it customizes how one of the built-in operators works). Just as a regular old free function can't access `private` fields of a class, a free function overloaded operator can't access `private` fields of the class it's overloading the operator for.

There are good reasons to do this. For example, it's really common for custom classes to overload `operator <<` with one argument being an `ostream` reference and the other being a custom type. It would be Really Bad if this custom overload could access the fields of the `ostream` type!

The fact that you defined `operator ==` inside of the implementation file for the class is also irrelevant. C++ doesn't have a notion of an "implementation file" for a class, even though typically that's how classes are implemented. It treats all source files as equal in that regard.

To fix this, you can declare your `operator ==` function to be a `friend` of the class:

```
class MyString {
public:
     ...
     friend bool operator== (const MyString& lhs, const MyString& rhs);
}

...

bool operator== (const MyString& lhs, const MyString& rhs) {
    // You were given explicit authorization to access private fields,
    // so go right ahead!
}
```

Independently, though, are you sure that your implementation of `operator ==` is correct? You're comparing the pointers stored in the `MyString` objects, not the contents of the strings that they point at. If you had two different copies of the same string literal in memory somewhere, you could have two `MyString`s that are logically equal (they represent the same string) but which don't compare equal.

In fact, you might want to ask a separate question: *can you implement `operator==` using just the public interface of the `MyString` type?* In a good string type, the answer should be "yes," since you should be able to access the characters in sequence and look at the length. From an efficiency perspective, this is less than ideal, but it's a good test to see whether the interface is good. So you might want to try implementing this function *without* using private fields just to make sure that you can, then think about the benefit of making `operator ==` a `friend` and whether it's a good idea from a performance perspective.